# Facebook registration plugin redirect

Tags: php, facebook, registration

I have facebook application on fan page and use registration plugin which connected to my system, registration form display in canvas of FB, when user sibmited the form he is redirecting to `redirect_uri` parameter in reg plugin, what should i put to this paramater, to display my redirect page in fb canvas, not in my site.

For example i have redirect parametr `http:\\mysite.com\success_registration.php`  with content text `thanks for registartion` and i wona display it in fb canvas... now it`s displaing like normal site page, but i dont wona see it so. User should stay in FB app canvas.

How can i solve such problem?
Thanks, Anton.

Answer (score 0):

Try app.facebook.com/[your app name]/success_registration.php

Make sure success_registration.php is in the folder specified in the setup for the app on your server (along with index.php usually)